# Python sqlite3: how to check if connection is an in-memory database?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

From Python's sqlite3 library, how can we determine if a connection belongs to a in-memory database?

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

def is_in_memory_connection(conn):
    # How to check if `conn` is an in-memory connection?
```

Is it possible to check the filename of an on-disk database? If so, I would presume that it would return `None` for an in-memory database.

Comment: Did the answer help solve your problem?

Comment: @zedfoxus Yes, but I was hoping for some way to check directly from the conn instead of executing a query. If I receive no answer from that perspective in a day or two I will mark yours as correct.

Comment: I see. I couldn’t find anything about the connection that could tell me about whether the db is using disk or memory. There’s a .show command through CLI, but we can’t run dot commands from Python connection.

Comment: @zedfoxus Too bad. And apparently there is a C API to get the filename of the connection (which is NULL for in memory databases), but it is not exposed in python's sqlite3.

Comment: You got it. Depending on your use case, you could use Python's subprocess to run sqlite3 CLI and capture `stdout` and then act upon it. But, that may have its own set of complexities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest I could come up with:

```
import sqlite3
 
def is_in_memory_connection(conn):
    local_cursor = conn.cursor()
    local_cursor.execute('pragma database_list')
    rows = local_cursor.fetchall()                                                       
    print(rows[0][2])
    return rows[0][2] == ''
 
#database = 'test.sqlite'
database = ':memory:'
conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
result = is_in_memory_connection(conn)
 
print(result)
```

If you have an in-memory database, database_list will show equivalent of this:

```
sqlite> pragma database_list;
seq  name  file
---  ----  ----
0    main
```

If you are opening a file that's on disk, it'll show the path of the file equivalent of this:

```
sqlite> pragma database_list;
seq  name  file                      
---  ----  --------------------------
0    main  /home/testing/test.sqlite
```

Taking advantage of this, you could call `pragma database_list` to show the file. If the path is empty, the database is not associated with a file.

https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_database_list